# ElasticSearch: get the bucket key inside bucket scripted_metric

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run this query in elasticsearch. Im trying to run a custom scripted_metric aggregation on my buckets. Within the metric script, I want to get access to the bucket key that it is aggregated on.

My documents in ES looks like this.

```
{
    user_id: 5,
    data: {
        5: 200,
        8: 300
    }
},
{
    user_id: 8,
    data: {
        5: 889,
        8: 22
    }
}
```

My aggregation query looks like this:

```
aggs = {
    approvers: {
        terms: {
            field: 'user_id'
        },
        aggs: {
            new_metric: {
                scripted_metric: {
                    map_script: `
                        // IS IT POSSIBLE TO GET THE BUCKET KEY HERE?
                        // The bucket key here would be the user_id
                        // so i can do stuff like

                        doc['data'][**_term**]....
                    `
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some digging and was likely having the same difficulty you were in finding a solution as to how to retrieve parent values... the only thing I could find was in regard to a special "_count" value on the child agg, but nothing related to its parent bucket names/keys.

If it's not a strict requirement to use a child agg with of a scripted_metric, I was able to find a way that allows you to at least access the bucket key within the parents. Maybe this can get you started in the direction of a solution:

```
aggs = {
    approvers: {
        terms: {
            field: 'user_id',
            script: '"There seems to be a magic value here: " + _value'
        }
}
```

Sample adapted from [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script)